# Kubernetes internal network and addresses not working for all internal names for same pod/service

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I am setting up a k8s cluster using k3s. Currently I have a [Jenkins pod](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins) running, set up according to [this guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/kubernetes/).

I have run into an issue [setting up the kubernetes cluster for Jenkins workers](https://chathura-siriwardhana.medium.com/configure-jenkins-with-kubernetes-e3175e02ca8) I can't seem to get my head wrapped around:

If I go to my Jenkins pod and start the console to test that the JNLP is working, not all the different names I can use work:

`curl localhost:50000` ✔ Works
`` curl `cat /etc/hostname`:50000 `` ✔ Works
`curl jenkins-service:50000` ❌ Times out

**BUT !!!**

`curl localhost:8080` ✔ Works
`` curl `cat /etc/hostname`:8080 `` ✔ Works
`curl jenkins-service:8080` ✔ Works

I then went back to the YAML and took a look at it. Appart from there being more references to 8080 than 50000 (8080 is a part of several urls and liveliness checks and so on), I do not see anything amiss

```yml
      containers:
        ...
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: httpport
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 50000
          name: jnlpport
          protocol: TCP
```

I have looked at [these](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-inbound-agent/issues/146) [defects](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/788) and the issues seem to not be the same, causing me to think that it must be Kubernetes related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [a detailed guide](https://devopscube.com/jenkins-build-agents-kubernetes/) which lead me to the answer...

In the service section only port 8080 was forwarded to 32000.

So I changed the service.yaml to be

```yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins-service
  namespace: devops-tools
  annotations:
      prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
      prometheus.io/path:   /
      prometheus.io/port:   '8080'
spec:
  selector:
    app: jenkins-server
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: httpport
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 32000
    - name: jnlpport
      port: 50000
      targetPort: 50000
```

and executed `kubectl apply -f service.yaml` which seems to have had an immediate effect.